# Saved image from google colab shows empty white space with noting on it

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, savefig

I tried saving the plot with following code

```
from google.colab import files
.....
plt.savefig('/content/drive/MyDrive/Project/firstone.jpeg' ,dpi=200,format='jpeg',bbox_inches='tight')
files.download('firstone.jpeg')
```

An image is saved but, it's with a blank white space with nothing on it, downloaded image is also same.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when I was trying to plot violin plots for my data using seaborn. I was not quite sure but I removed the plt.show() before this exact few lines as you have mentioned and it worked.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).